# Arguments in braces replaced by a command

Tags: macros

I have `\somecmd` that acts on some number of arguments in braces: `\somecmd{{arg1},{arg2}}`.

I'd like to create a `\myargs` command that expands to `{args1},{args2}` and use `\somecmd{\myargs}`.

Comment: Welcome! And what is the question?

Comment: Thanks, how to create such command \myargs ?

Comment: @Tonechas: thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is

```
\newcommand\somecmd[2]{...}
\newcommand\myargs{{arg1}{arg2}}
\expandafter\somecmd\myargs
```

which will first expand the macro `\myargs`  once, leaving the braced arguments in the input stream, and then expand `\somecmd` so it can use the arguments. Make sure to not have an commas in the argument list, just the braced groups.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for `\@for`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DoWhatever}[1]{I do something with #1\par}
\newcommand{\MultiArg}[1]{\@for\next:=#1\do{\DoWhatever{\next}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MultiArg{{arg1},{arg2}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This also works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DoWhatever}[1]{I do something with #1\par}
\newcommand{\MultiArg}[1]{\@for\next:=#1\do{\DoWhatever{\next}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myargs{{arg1},{arg2}}
\MultiArg{\myargs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you but instead of \MultiArg{{arg1},{arg2}} I want typing \MultiArg{\myargs} where \myargs expands to {args1},{args2}

Comment: @adnen This also works. Please see the explicit example I added.

Comment: Yes sir that's it (sorry for my bad english)